# data not send to logentries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net, logentries

Who use log4net with logentries? I was did all on [documentation](https://logentries.com/doc/dotnet/) 
Application mvc asp.
Token get from Logging's settings .

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="Logentries.Token" value="...xx-xx-xx..." /> 
... 
</appSettings> 

<log4net> 
<appender name="LeAppender" type="log4net.Appender.LogentriesAppender, LogentriesLog4net"> 
<token value="...xx-xx-xx..." /> 
.... 
</appender>
```

This settings duplicated in  App.config and Web.config
In script

```
Log.Info("check log...");
```

log4net write in .txt file, but not send to site. Why? (

Comment: Add <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/> and you will be able to see what is the problem.

Comment: where to look ? Error list ?

Comment: You can see the info in Output/Debug console, LE will write the details

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue then found the root cause is about connection to LE is blocking at the network, but must check below points:

- Configure log4net in AssemblyInfo.cs but you have log in .txt file so it should be OK: `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`
- Be sure to have correct token in appSettings: `<add key="Logentries.Token" value="XYZ...."/>`
- Debugging your app, check Output/Debug console it will tell the detail

[image]

Comment: Here the sample code: https://github.com/vndevpro/logentries-with-log4net